# Unknown Cause of Syntax Error in Main - Java

Tags: arrays, exception, syntax, compilation

Here's my question: I'm coding a program, but the program throws an exception, and I don't know why or how to fix it. Here's the code:

```
public class ArraySortingTiming {
    int i = 10;
    int[] array1 = new int[i];
    int[] array2 = new int[i];
    
    for (int a = 0; a < array1.length() ||a < array2.length(); a++) {
        int n = (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE * Math.random());
        array1[a] = n;
        array2[a] = n;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArraySortingTiming a = new ArraySortingTiming();


    }

}
```

And here's the exception message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    Syntax error on token ")", ; expected 

at programmingassignments.ArraySortingTiming.main(ArraySortingTiming.java:14)
```

I tried changing each array definition to int[] array1 = new int[10]; eliminating the i constant, but it still doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your main() is nested inside the public class. it should be outside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your for loop block inside your main function.

Comment: How thoughtful of you! This solved my problem.